# NPM Angular ERR! peerInvalid / peerDependencies requirements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, node-sass

When running npm install on this package.json

```
{
"author": ", Inc.",
"name": "-angular2-template",
"version": "0.2.0",
"description": "Angular 2 Project Template. Webpack, ES6, Sass, Karma.",
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://dev..net//-angular-template/issues"
},
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git@dev..net:/-angular-template.git"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently -k -r \"npm run webpack:w\" \"npm run sass:w\" \"npm run lite\"",
  "build": "NODE_ENV='production' npm run webpack:b && npm run sass:b",
  "webpack:b": "webpack",
  "webpack:w": "webpack -w",
  "sass": "node-sass --source-map true src/scss/index.scss build/styles.css",
  "sass:b": "node-sass --output-style compressed src/scss/index.scss build/styles.css",
  "sass:w": "npm run sass; node-sass --source-map true -w src/scss/index.scss build/styles.css",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "postinstall": "typings install",
  "typings": "typings"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
  "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.2",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "firebase": "^3.3.0",
  "js-data": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
  "js-data-http": "^3.0.0-beta.8",
  "lodash": "^4.6.1",
  "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "tslint": "^3.13.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
  "autoprefixer": "^6.3.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
  "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
  "codelyzer": "0.0.25",
  "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
  "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
  "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
  "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
  "karma": "^0.13.22",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
  "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
  "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
  "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
  "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
  "postcss": "^5.0.21",
  "postcss-loader": "^0.9.1",
  "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
  "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
  "tslint-eslint-rules": "^1.3.0",
  "tslint-loader": "^2.1.5",
  "typescript": "^1.8.10",
  "typings": "^1.0.4",
  "webpack": "^1.13.0"
}
```

}

I get the following errors..

```
         typings WARN deprecated 8/18/2016: "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
  typings WARN deprecated 7/25/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
  typings WARN deprecated 6/21/2016: "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
  typings WARN deprecated 7/24/2016: "registry:dt/webpack#1.12.9+20160523035535" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

  ├── core-js (global)
  ├── jasmine (global)
  ├── moment (global)
  ├── node (global)
  ├── source-map (global)
  ├── uglify-js (global)
  └── webpack (global)

  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\angularfire2 requires @angular/common@'^2.0.0-rc.5' but will load
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\@angular\common,
  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.4
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\angularfire2 requires @angular/compiler@'^2.0.0-rc.5' but will load
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\@angular\compiler,
  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.4
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\angularfire2 requires @angular/core@'^2.0.0-rc.5' but will load
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\@angular\core,
  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.4
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\angularfire2 requires @angular/platform-browser@'^2.0.0-rc.5' but will load
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser,
  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.4
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\angularfire2 requires @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^2.0.0-rc.5' but will load
  npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Modal\ng2-crm-revamp\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic,
  npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.0-rc.4
  npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
  npm ERR! node v4.5.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
  npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

  npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.4 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.4 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@0.3.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.5
  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.1 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
  npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-bootstrap@1.0.24 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4
```

I've tried a fresh npm install. I've tried running `npm install npm -g` and I've tried clearing out `node_modules`both globally and in appdata. I've Googled around and found next to nothing. Perhaps it's because my Googling is bad. Or perhaps because there's actually nothing to find. I'm not sure. But I'm flustered and this feels like the time to make my first Stackoverflow post, although it definitely feels more like a plea than anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly telling you what's wrong. You are installing some angular2 with the latest release and some from  previous version and that's why you are getting good this error. Try to install all the latest or only previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Install Latest version nodejs ([nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)). try again. `npm install`